# BibTex error: Can't find any citations, bibdata or bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, texshop

been writing up my thesis and everything works pretty well except for the citations and the bibliography.

I am using a Tex file that is split up into different parts which I include using the `\input {something.tex}` command.
Everything compiles just fine, except when I try to compile the document again using Bibtex I get the following output:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
The top-level auxiliary file: BA.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 00-Titel_etc/Titelblatt.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: 00-Titel_etc/eidesstattliche_Erklaerung.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file BA.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file BA.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file BA.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

I call the citations in the subfiles using for example: `\cite {Scott.2011}`
with the corresponding line in the .bib file: `@article{Scott.2011, …}`

I call the bibliography using the following:

```
\defbibheading{Literaturverzeichnis}{\section{Literaturverzeichnis}}
\bibliographystyle {plain}
\bibliography {Quellen} 
\nocite {*} 
\printbibliography[heading=Literaturverzeichnis]
```

And my bibliography file is in the same folder as the overall Tex file (namely BA.tex).
But even with the `\nocite {*}` command all I get on the bibliography page is the output "Quellen" which is the name of my .bib file.

Don't actually know what I am doing wrong… been googling all over the internet, found similar problems, but none of the solutions brought any help or even change.
I am using Texshop on a Mac by the way.

Appreciate any kind of help or hint as to what to try or do!!!!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You are using `biblatex` by the look of things: do you have `backend=bibtex` in the options when loading it? If not, it will default to Biber, which uses a different mechanism to pass data.

Comment: `Scott.2001` or `Scott.2011`?

Comment: @Sigur 2011 of course… has been edited. thx.

Comment: @JosephWright: tex shop provides me with a drop down menu to recompile my file using bibtex. how and where would i have to apply the `backend=bibtex`option?

Comment: @budekatude Nothing to do with your editor. Somewhere in your preamble you have a line `\usepackage{biblatex}` or similar, which needs to have the option if you are using BibTeX, _e.g._ `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much JosephWright!
That works perfect!
You just made my day!

Comment: You are mixing biblatex (`\printbibliography`) and non-biblatex-code (`\bibliographystyle`) that's not a good idea. And if you want to use biblatex you should better change your editor so that is uses biber instead of adding backend=bibtex. See e.g. http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1909/wie-verwende-ich-biber-in-meinem-editor