# Bibliography with BibLateX, Biber and Winedt 9

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I started doing LaTeX less than one week ago, so I am completely fresh to the game. To be quick: I am running Windows 8 (probably not relevant), my LaTeX sits on MikTeX 2.9 but I am using Winedt 9 as editor. I want to learn how to make a bibliography for my upcoming thesis. I am using the biblatex package, and I have also loaded the biber package.

In the preamble, I use the commands `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` and `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`, which is the "default" bibliography that came with the biblatex package (located in a directory under MikteX 2.9/bibtex/etx.) In the document, I use the command `\cite{aristotle1968}` and at before I end the document, I use `\printbibliography`.

I can LaTeX this with some warnings, but I doesn't BibTeX. It gives me the following error messages:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux

(There were 3 error messages)
```

What is wrong? I saw a guy who had the exact same problem here: [BibTex error: Can't find any citations, bibdata or bibstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187087/bibtex-error-cant-find-any-citations-bibdata-or-bibstyle)

But the solution that worked for him, that is specifying the `[backend=biber]` in the preamble, does not work for me.

Please, help... I have already googled this for three full days and read tons of suggestions...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations. Biber is _not_ a package, it's a tool which is used in place of BibTeX for extracting data from the `.bib` file.

Comment: If you specify `backend=biber` when you load `biblatex`, then you need to use Biber (the program) instead of BibTeX (the program). Your editor of choice may be trying to use BibTeX rather than Biber, which then explains why the file `test.aux` (created when you run LaTeX (for sake of simplicity: the program) on the file `test.tex`) does not contain the citation information. BibTeX is run on `test.aux`, while Biber is run on `test.bcf` (by running LaTeX on `test.tex`), which should be created given that the file contains `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`.

Comment: There are at least two issues here: First and foremost, `biblatex-examples.bib` does not contain an entry `aristotle1968`, there are some works by Aristotle, but their keys are `aristotle:poetics` and so forth. You need to cite an entry that exists, for example `\cite{sigfridsson}`, or for your fix of ancient Greek philosophers `\cite{aristotle:poetics}`. Secondly, and also very importantly, your editor seems to run BibTeX and not Biber (which you explicitly requested), see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=93132#p93132)

Comment: I know that Biber is a program, but according to thi link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows     it should be possible to just add biber as a package in Package Manager. I have checked, and I use Miktex 32 bit. It seems my editor, Winedt 9, still runds BibTex although I tell it to run Biber... I still don't know what to do. Thanks Moewe, for pointing out my mistake in citing the entry to Aristotle.

Comment: And now I have even installed the Biber program. During the installation I was asked if I wanted to replae Biber with the already existing file, so it seems the package download actually IS the same by now. But even so, and after rebooting, and using the command everyone says I should use, i.e. \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} I still get the same 3 error messages, suggesting Winedt is still calling BibTeX. I am considering quitting my job and not do the thesis. Perhaps BibTeX is Skynet...

Comment: Skynet? Stop being suspicious. You are dealing with computer programs. Please carefully read the links i have been gibing you on LC and stop panicking.

Comment: If you still get the three lines you are indeed not calling Biber, delete all auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`). Make sure you have set up your editor exactly as in the link above and try again. Also check if you really have installed Biber, that is very easily done by typing `biber --version` in the command line and wait for the output. You should only install Biber via the package manager, all other (manual) methods can lead to problems later. Also make sure your system is up to date to avoiud version mismatches.

Comment: Did you get any further? I would have thought our best guess is that your editor is not configured correctly, but please go through the steps at [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) to check for common Biber problems.

Comment: I will vote to close the question as a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the `Latexify` set of macros package, available from [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php).

It will add a number of items to your WinEdt menus and buttons:[image]

After you've compiled your main file with (pdf)latex once, you commpile the bibliography with `biber` either from the drop-down TeX menu, selecting `biber` or from the `B+` button, and finally recompile with (pdf)latex twice.

Comment: I have already the Latexify set of macros, but the Biber-option does not appear on my TeX-list in Winedt. Seems like Winedt just refuses to find Biber...

Comment: Maybe this is linked to the fact that `biber 64 bit` is quite recent, and if you had  MiKTeX 64 bit, you didn't have access to Biber 32 bit (at least it was not installed on 64 bit systems). Is your installation recent enough?

Comment: It's all very recent, because I just started using LaTeX. I downloaded MikTeX 2.9, 32 bits, some weeks ago. And I downloaded Biber yesterday...

Comment: The only explanation I see is   installation of Latexify_9 did not run correctly. Try unstalling (from `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Uninstall\LaTeXify`), and reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard for your effort to help me. My Winedt does not reside in that folder on my computer, it seems. But I now ran the uninstallation the same way I ran the installation: By simpling dragging the file "uninstall.edt" into Winedt and by choosing "Execute Macro Script" from the "Macros" toolbar. This is the installation mode described at the homepage Winedt.org. However, when I do, it gives me 5 warnings, saying that the following files were not found: ConfigEx\Mainmenu.ini, ConfigEx\Toolbar.ini, Exec\Erase Working Files.edt, Exec\TeX\PDFTeXify.edt, Exec\TeX\TeXify.edt...

Comment: The folder I mentioned is not the installation folder of WinEdt itself, but an auxiliary folder automatically created by WinEdt to store personal configuration files and the like. Normally `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData` is a hidden folder.